# Trouble adding a path to a group but not a rectangle for the same data on d3.js v4, not reading .attr("d", d3.line())

Tags: d3.js, data-binding, path

I have been working with d3.js for the past few weeks and one of the main issues I keep running into is appending paths to a group. In this example, I am trying to make a line chart with curved lines. I am able to add the curve I want to the .svg no problem. But when I try to add it to the group I have defined, it doesn't show up. In troubleshooting, I made rectangles which are placed in the group and according tot he data. The only difference, then, between the rectangles that do show up and my curve that doesn't is the shape. What am I missing?

I define a variable for the svg and another for the group:

```
        var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 27 + ", 27 )");
```

I add axes to the group

```
            g.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


            g.append("g")
                //.attr("transform", "translate(50, 0 )")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(yleft));
```

And then I try and make my curve. Here, I show the successful addition to the svg, the unsuccessful addition to the group, and the successful addition of the rectangles to the group.

```
//curve that shows up on the svg
            svg.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                .attr("d", d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Time) ;})
                    .y(function(d) { return yleft(d.soc) ; })
                    .curve(d3.curveBasis));

//curve that doesn't show up on the g
            g.append("g")
                .selectAll("path") 
                .data(data) 
                .enter() 
                .append("path") created
                .attr("stroke", "#60105d")
                .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                .attr("d", d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return (d.Time) ; })
                    .y(function(d) { return (d.soc); })
                    .curve(d3.curveBasis))

//rectangles that show up on the g
            g.append("g")
                .selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.Time) ;})
                .attr("y", function(d) {return yleft(d.soc) ;})
                .attr("width", 20)
                .attr("height", 20)
                .attr("fill", "black")
```

When I look in Chrome developper, I see that the the paths are appended to the group, but for some reason, the .attr("d", arc.line()/...) is not being read because all I see is:

```
<g>
     <path fill="none" stroke="#60105d" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
     <path fill="none" stroke="#60105d" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
     <path fill="none" stroke="#60105d" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
     <path fill="none" stroke="#60105d" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
.
.
.
```

(I was unable to upload a picture)

What is going on here?

Comment: It appears that your data array contains an array of points, so you create a rect for each point, but you do not want to create a path for each point (which is what you appear to be doing), you want to create one path for all points, so you need to pass a data array that contains an array of paths (where each path is an array of points): `.data([data])`.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. the difference between rect and path makes sense now. I just had to copy-paste what I wrote to add the curve to the svg, change "svg" to "g" and "data" to "datum". It's helpful to remember datum is needed to bind data to a single svg element, in this case, the path.